# variable declaration doesn't compile with rollup

Tags: typescript, bundle, rollup

I run a project with TS bundled with rollup.
Using:

```
"typescript": "^4.6.3",
"rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.31.2",
"rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
```

When I compile my code with `tsc -d --emitDeclarationOnly --declarationDir build/types` everything builds fine, but with `rollup -c` throws an `(plugin rpt2) syntax error TS1134: Variable declaration expected.`

For this part of code:

```
interface MyJson {
    default: () => Record<string, unknown>;
}

// ERROR on following line:
export const myVariable: () => Promise<MyJson> = () =>
new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
    resolve({
        default: () => {
            return {};
        },
    });
});
```

I presume something conflicts rollup to compile with ts. But can't see what's wrong.

I've setup `tsconfig` with:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

And `rollup.config.js` with:

```js
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import sucrase from "@rollup/plugin-sucrase";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2"; // switched to plugin2 to have better error input


export default [
    {
        input: pathResolve("src/index.ts"),
        output: [
            {
                file: pathResolve("dist/index.es.js"),
                format: "esm",
            },
            {
                file: pathResolve("dist/index.js"),
                format: "cjs",
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            typescript({
                target: "esnext",
                module: "esnext",
                declaration: true,
            }),
            commonjs({
                include: nodeModules,
                extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".json"],
            }),
            json(),
            resolve(),
            sucrase({
                exclude: [nodeModules],
                transforms: ["typescript"],
            }),
        ],
        context: "window",
    },
```

I cannot see what goes wrong. Is there a wrong set up of rollup for TS? or it's a rollup inefficiency with ts?

Comment: Is `myVariable` supposed to have an initial value of `undefined`?

Comment: yes - I don't care for its value. it will be filled by `replace` plugin at bundle time

Comment: see updated post @MaartenDev

Comment: What version of `typescript` and `rollup-plugin-typescript2` are you using?

Comment: "typescript": "^4.6.3"
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.31.2",
@MaartenDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by moving the plugins on the rollup configuration
Seems like there's a conflict and typescript needs to be first above the other plugins.

```
    export default [
        {
          ...
            plugins: [
               resolve(),
               typescript(),
               replace({
                  DYNAMIC_IMPORT_MANIFEST: `"${externalManifestFile}"`,
                  preventAssignment: true,
                  dest: "dist",
               }),
               commonjs({
                include: nodeModules,
                extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".mjs", ".json"],
              }),
            ],
            context: "window",
        },
```